# java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml

Tags: jenkins

I have my Jenkins running on 8080 port and the service is up and running but while accessing the home page I am getting the below error :

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
    at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:165)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.loadConfig(Jenkins.java:3063)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.access$1200(Jenkins.java:304)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$14.run(Jenkins.java:3081)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1065)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:269)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:47)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1099)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:904)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:86)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:82)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:233)
Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:250)
```

Can anyone please suggest me what needs to be done here?

Answer (score 0):

The most suspected reason for this would be that you do not have permissions to write data to that file, probably only read. Open up your terminal and write `sudo chown $(whoami) /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml`.

This answer is given in part while refering to this answer relating to Android permission issues, where the only thing that worked was [changing ownership of the SDK dir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58691626/11889667), solution as given by user [Eytan Manor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7770688/eytan-manor).

You might want to set permissions for that whole folder if you need full access to more than just that file using `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /var/lib/jenkins`.